# Как присвоить несколько значений?

Tags: php

Вот код

```
 <?php
 $dr = $_GET['dr'];    
 if(empty($dr)){ echo "dr is empty...";}
 elseif($dr == 'kola'){(include 'k.php');}
 elseif($dr == 'vova'){ echo "vova2";}
 ?>
```

Как к `elseif($dr == 'kola')` присвоить несколько значений? например `kola2 kola3 kolyan kolka`  итд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(in_array($dr, array('kola2', 'kola3', 'kolyan', 'kolka'))){
//some code;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, а еще один вопрос. Как сделать чтобы эти значения брались из файла? например из s.php? Попробывал include но что-то невыходит

Comment: А как они у вас в файле хранятся?

Comment: пишешь в другом файле код:

    $x = array('kola2', 'kola3', 'kolyan', 'kolka');

делаешь его include, и проверяешь

    if(in_array($dr, $x)){

Comment: вот так 'kola2', 'kola3', 'kolyan', 'kolka'

Comment: Вам @IVsevolod написал как надо сделать

Comment: $x = (include 's.php');  вот так?

Comment: @Александр Дахно - нет, просто сделайте включение без присвоения, объявленный массив в s.php будет доступен по тому же имени и в вашем файле.

> include 's.php';
> if(in_array($dr, $x)){}

Так.

Comment: хочется конечно чтобы перечислить эти значения без ковычек(если это возможно) через новую строку
например
kola2
kola3
kolyan
kolka

Comment: Если это будет текстовый файл, то задачу надо решать при помощи функции [file_get_contents][1].

UPD: @Deonis - оу оу, полегче с array_map и анонимными функциями, тут с файлами и массивами справиться не можем.

[1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Если файл текстовый, то как вариант:

    $str = file_get_contents('file.txt'); // так считываем файл в строку
    $arr = explode(',',$str); // так разбиваем строку по запятой и получаем массив
    $arr = array_map(function($a){
     return trim($a,"' ");
    }, $arr); // так (или другим способом) убираем лишние пробелы и кавычки

Answer (score 0):

```
else if(($dr == 'kola') && ($dr == 'sss') && ($dr == 'ssss') && ($dr == 'sss1wawadwa'))
```